# how to create hide and show panel over the google maps?

Tags: html, css

I need help because I'm not good with CSS. I want to create a floating hide and show panel on google maps similar to the example here :
http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/J8U25/

But I'm still failing. here is the screenshot:
 when hidden :
[image]

when I click the red button to show panel :
[image]

here is my CSS :

```
#map-canvas {
  margin:0;
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  height: 650px;
  z-index:1;
  max-width: none;
}

#click {
  margin:0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  float: right; 
  margin-top: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#floating-panel {
  float:right;
  width: 17%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 90px;      
}
```

and here is my html tag :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="floating-panel">
        <b>Start: </b>
        <select id="start">
          <option value="Stasiun Pondok Cina">Pondok Cina</option>
        </select>
        <br> <b>End: </b>
        <select id="end">
          <option size="25" value="Margonda Residence">Margonda Residence</option>
        </select>
      </div> 
      <div id='click'></div>
      <div id="map-canvas" ></div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

thanks for your help :)

Comment: It seems that you need to style the `select` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have take the jsfiddle that you provided and reproduce the solution as I have posted below you can check it, and here is the fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/meily/J8U25/1765/:

```
 <div class="container-fluid map-container">
    <div class="row">
    <div id='panel'>

        Hi!
        <div id="floating-panel">
        <b>Start: </b>
        <select id="start">
      <option value="Stasiun Pondok Cina">Pondok Cina</option>

       </select>
       <br> <b>End: </b>
        <select id="end">
      <option size="25" value="Margonda Residence">Margonda Residence</option>

        </select>

        </div> 
    </div>
    <div id='click'>
    </div>

    <div class="map-canvas-container">
    <div id="map-canvas">
    <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=USA&key=AIzaSyAN0om9mFmy1QN6Wf54tXAowK4eT0ZUPrU">

    </iframe>
    </div>
    <a class="embedded-map-code" href="https://www.hostingreviews.website/compare/namecheap-vs-fatcow" id="get-data-for-embed-map">fatcow namecheap</a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

This is the css:

```
.map-container {
    position: relative;
}
#panel
{
     height: 500px;
     background: black;
     opacity: 0.9;
     float: left;
     display: none;    
     color: white;
     font-size: xx-large;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
      z-index:1;
}
#click
{
     height: 50px;
     width: 25px;
     background: red;
     float: left; 
     margin-top: 200px;
     z-index: 1;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
}

.map-canvas-container {
   overflow:hidden;
   width:1000px;
   height:500px;
   resize:none;
   max-width:100%;
}

iframe {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   border:0;
}

#embed-map-canvas img{
   max-width:none!important;
   background:none!important;
   font-size: inherit;
}
#map-canvas {
   margin:0;
   float: left;
   width: 70%;
   position: absolute;
   padding: 0;
   height:100%; 
   width:100%;
   max-width:100%;
}
```

This is the jQuery code for that:

```
$('#click').click(function()
{
    $("#panel").animate({width:'toggle'},500);       
});
```

Comment: woowww that's great, how when i want red button position follow by slide panel? have an idea?

Comment: by wrapping up the panel with another div name it panel-container and set its position to absolute, with left 0, and z-index of 1, and and change the mark up part by cut the div class click and put it into the same level of the div#panel inside #panel-container you can achieved your desired outcome. however i update the fiddle so yeah that's it. http://jsfiddle.net/meily/J8U25/1779/

Comment: if this solved your problem mark my answer as corrected please... :D